# Get the classes folder for an off build process in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am building a script, I want to do this to build an array of folders to pass to another off gradle process as the class path.  The first two lines work just fine, but the one on the bottom errors out.  i can't find anything in the documentation to do this.  how do i make this last line work?

```
classpathCollection = classpathCollection + files(project(':GWT:componentTester').sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
classpathCollection = classpathCollection + files(project(':GWT:componentTester').sourceSets.main.resources)
classpathCollection = classpathCollection + files(project(':GWT:componentTester').output.classesDir)
```

In case it matters, this off gradle process is the GWT devmode and superdev processes.  in order for them to run correctly, they need the sources and the classes.  figuring out the syntax for the sources was a 2 day project and now im stuck again on the class folder.  can i get som

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to also get that from the 'main' sourceSet, see also: [23.7 Working with source sets](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec%3asource_sets)

```
files(project(':GWT:componentTester').sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
```

Comment: `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` seems to be deleted with Gradle 5.x. Was deprecated in 4.x